# MS SQL Server 2005 sp_stored_procedures

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm currently running the

```
sp_stored_procedures
```

stored procedure to retrieve a listing of SP for a given data source. I will need to query this dataset by it's PROCEDURE_NAME and PROCEDURE_OWNER columns. However, PROCEDURE_NAME seems to have a strange return value. It seems to append a semicolon and a number to the end of the name.

```
sel_AppUser;1
sel_AppUser_all;1
sel_AppUser_by_login;1
sel_Browsable;1
```

Here's sel_Browsable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sel_Browsable]
@BrowsableID uniqueidentifier
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Browsable WHERE browsableID = @BrowsableID FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
SELECT * FROM Attribute WHERE objectID = @BrowsableID FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
SELECT * FROM Search WHERE browsableID = @BrowsableID ORDER BY searchOrder FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
SELECT Attribute.* FROM Attribute INNER JOIN Search ON Attribute.objectID = Search.searchID WHERE browsableID = @BrowsableID ORDER BY searchOrder FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
SELECT Criterion.* FROM Criterion INNER JOIN Search ON Criterion.searchID = Search.searchID WHERE browsableID = @BrowsableID ORDER BY searchOrder, criterionOrder FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
SELECT Attribute.* FROM Attribute INNER JOIN Criterion ON Attribute.objectID = Criterion.criterionID INNER JOIN Search ON Criterion.searchID = Search.searchID WHERE browsableID = @BrowsableID ORDER BY searchOrder, criterionOrder FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
SELECT CriterionOperator.* FROM CriterionOperator INNER JOIN Criterion ON CriterionOperator.criterionID = Criterion.criterionID INNER JOIN Search ON Criterion.searchID = Search.searchID WHERE browsableID = @BrowsableID ORDER BY searchOrder, criterionOrder, operatorOrder FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
SELECT CriterionValue.* FROM CriterionValue INNER JOIN Criterion ON CriterionValue.criterionID = Criterion.criterionID INNER JOIN Search ON Criterion.searchID = Search.searchID WHERE browsableID = @BrowsableID ORDER BY searchOrder, criterionOrder, criterionValueOrder FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
END
```

Initially I thought that these numbers might represent the number of parameters (until NUM_INPUT_PARAMS is implemented in SQL Server) but I've added and removed parameters and haven't seen a change in the listing.

What do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have different stored procedures with the same name, differentiated by numbers, wich can be dropped together at once. The syntax is [still valid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) as of SQL 2k8:

> ; number Is an optional integer that
>   is used to group procedures of the
>   same name. These grouped procedures
>   can be dropped together by using one
>   DROP PROCEDURE statement. For example,
>   an application called orders might use
>   procedures named orderproc;1,
>   orderproc;2, and so on. The DROP
>   PROCEDURE orderproc statement drops
>   the whole group. If the name contains
>   delimited identifiers, the number
>   should not be included as part of the
>   identifier; use the appropriate
>   delimiter around only procedure_name.

The feature is on the [official deprecated list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx).

BTW you can use the catalog views to retrieve the procedures: [sys.procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx). I find using the views much easier than using the procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what they mean - it could be the version?

But I'd recommend an alternative to sp_stored_procedures:

```
select specific_schema, specific_name, * from information_schema.routines
```

It gives you the name and owner (among other things), and it doesn't have strange characters.

Answer (score 0):

See the MSDN documentation for [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx). Under the "Arguments" section, for procedure_name, they say that adding that sort of number is deprecated. From the syntax diagram, the ;1 is not part of the procedure name, and is optional. Since the ; character isn't legal in [T-SQL identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), you can just look at the string before ; in the query results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a type where 0=Function and 1=Stored Procedure.